# How to remove all tags after certain tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove tags going after `#first` and only in `#container`.
How can I do it with jQuery?

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="remove_me_1"></div>
  <div id="remove_me_2"></div>
  <div id="remove_me_3"></div>
  <a href="" id="remove_me_too">Remove me too</a>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `nextAll` method: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

```
$("#first").nextAll().remove();
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple, deleted my slightly (but only slightly) more complicated answer.

Comment: The selector should be `#container #first` as required in the question.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, there should be a single `#first` element in the page.

Comment: @Ionut: yes, but it may not always be in `#container` on every page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.("#container #first ~ *").remove();
```

Comment: -1 the universal selector * should be avoided whereever possible.

Comment: @jAndy, is there any evidence that your statement applies in the context of jQuery? I know CSS selectors are matched right to left, but I'm not so sure jQuery does the same. It may be the case with `querySelectorAll` though.

Comment: So Sizzle matches right to left when not using `querySelectorAll` actually?

Comment: Ok, it appears `querySelectorAll` does the same right to left processing.

Comment: You could always do something like: `$("#container #first").find("~ *")` to limit the search first.

Comment: I'm not even sure if that would avoid the universal selector to grab all nodes first. However, the star is just bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#container :gt(0)").remove();
```