# Remove all elements after certain element

Tags: jquery

My code is:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="element1" class="ewrap"></div>
  <div id="element2" class="ewrap"></div>
  <div id="element3" class="ewrap"></div>
  <div id="element4" class="ewrap"></div>
  <div id="element5" class="ewrap"></div>
</div>
```

How would I *dynamically* remove all elements after `element1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all tags after certain tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817833/how-to-remove-all-tags-after-certain-tag)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You could use the [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method:

```
$('#element1').nextAll('div').remove();
```

Comment: I could kiss you

Comment: But it works only if all elements are at same level